# How send base64 value to API?

Tags: angular, typescript

**html**

```
<img [src]="imageUrl"  style="width:250px;height:200px">
<input  id="imageNameId" type="file"  #Image accept="image/*"  formControlName="imageName" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)"/>
```

**add-component.ts**

```
handleFileInput(file: FileList) {
this.imageName = file.item(0);
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = (event:any) => {
  this.imageUrl = event.target.result;
}
reader.readAsDataURL(this.imageName);
}
```

handleFileInput converting image to base64, how to send value to addImage(): void from handleFileInput?

```
addImage(): void {

let image = automapper.map(
  'ImageFormModel',
  'ImageForCreation',
  this.imageForm.value);
this.tourService.addImage(image)
  .subscribe(
    () => {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/image');
    })
 }
```

Comment: Can you try to better explain what you are trying to achieve and what you have tried so far?

Comment: handleFileInput - shows me image immediately, and it is converting to base64 code. I want to send this base64 value to addImage void. I tried : addImage(this.imageName): void {
this.tourService.addImage(this.imageName)
      .subscribe(
        () => {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/image');
        })
  }} And lot of other things, but i still don't understand how typescript works

Answer (score 0):

**If both methods are in the same file:**

If `addImage() {...}` is in the same file, you can simply call it inside the `handleFileInput` using `this.addImage()`. Inside the `addImage` method, since the `addImage` method is in the same file as `handleFileInput` it will also have access to `this.imageUrl`

**If both methods are in the different files:**

If `addImage() {...}` is not in the same file, you can simply make the `addImage()` method a parametrized one. While calling it inside the `handleFileInput` since it is going to be a part of a different file, probably a service(let's call it `ImageService` for the sake of this example), you'll have to first inject that service as a dependency in the Component that you're working on.

```
constructor(..., private imageService: ImageService, ...) {}
```

Then you can call it using `this.imageService.addImage(this.imageUrl)`.

Inside the `addImage` method, since the `addImage` method will now be accepting the Image Base 64 url via the parameter, it will get the image url.

### UPDATE 1:

From the [**GitHub repo that you shared**](https://stackblitz.com/github/IndreBaranauskaite/Angular-API/tree/master/TourManagement.Client?file=src%2Fapp%2Fimage%2Fimage-add%2Fimage-add.component.ts), it seems that these two methods are in the same file. So like I said in my above answer, you should be able to get the URL using `this.imageUrl`. Just use that in your `addImage` method instead of `this.imageForm.value`:

```
addImage(): void {
  let image = automapper.map(
    'ImageFormModel',
    'ImageForCreation',
    this.imageUrl);
  this.tourService.addImage(image)
    .subscribe(
      () => {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/image');
      })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but answer is not what i expected. It is really difficult to explain for me but I will try. You see method handleFileInput encode image to base64(" 9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4TOeRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAEQALAAIAAAAmAAAI5gEAAAMAAAABEgAAAAE...") and method addImage(): send image value to my api. but at the moment I receive to api only image name ("IMG_20180916_181546.jpg") but i want get value from handleFileInput. Is it posible?

Comment: Do you have this code somewhere? I'd need that to help you out. It would be great if you could create a [Minimal Verifiable Complete Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) You can create one using [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular)

Comment: I have it in github https://github.com/IndreBaranauskaite/Angular-API/tree/master/TourManagement.Client/src/app/image

Comment: Not sure what is this `automapper` thing in the code? Anyway, I've updated the answer regarding what you asked. I think that should fix the issue for you.

Comment: sad but now value is null

Answer (score 0):

*Finally it works*
**html**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="imageNameId">Image Name</label>
<div class="col-md-8">
<img [src]="imageUrl"  style="width:250px;height:200px">
<input  id="imageNameId" type="file"  #Image accept="image/*"     formControlName="imageName" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)"/>
<textarea id="base64textarea" placeholder="Base64 will appear here" cols="50" rows="15" formControlName="imageNameURL">{{imageUrl}}</textarea>
</div>
</div>
```

**image-add.component.ts**

```
addImage(): void {

let image = automapper.map(
  'ImageFormModel',
  'ImageForCreation',
  this.imageForm.value);
  image.imageName = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("base64textarea")).value;  
this.tourService.addImage(image)
  .subscribe(
    () => {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/image');
    })

    console.log(image)
 }
```